# Full text search(FTS) postgres 9.1 _ removal

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, plpgsql

I want to execute a full text search(FTS) on a table. The problem is that the tsvector removes the underscore in words(like: person_id becomes person and id). Where can i configure that it will kee the underscore?

Ty in advance guys

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you're going to have to write your own parser (or tweak the existing one, in any case). If you take a look at [ts_debug](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-parsers.html)'s output then you'll see that it treats the underscore as a space.

```
=> SELECT ts_debug('person_id');
                                 ts_debug                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (asciiword,"Word, all ASCII",person,{english_stem},english_stem,{person})
 (blank,"Space symbols",_,{},,)
 (asciiword,"Word, all ASCII",id,{english_stem},english_stem,{id})
(3 rows)
```

This is happening before it gets fed into the dictionary for language-specific treatment.

So - you'll need to break out your text editor, find the parser in the source code and convince it that the underscore should be treated like e.g. a hyphen or some such). Shouldn't be too bad if you've done any C before.

Comment: Ty for the quik reply! I have to do this in postgres i think? Because postgres saves _ as a space(does not matter if it is a string or a text). Can you guide me to the file which i have to modify?

Comment: I'd start with src/backend/tsearch/ts_parse.c, but if you seriously couldn't figure that out yourself then adapting the parser code might be beyond your reach.